# Derivation of openssl / bouncycastle generated certificate chain fails in Adobe Reader on signing

Tags: java, pdf, openssl, bouncycastle, adobe-reader

We use openssl to generate a self signed root certificate and derive a user certificate from it with Java using the bouncycastle library. The user certificate is used to sign PDF documents again from java with a mix of bouncycastle and openssl.

The root certificate is installed in Adobe Reader, but Adobe reader says, signature is invalid because there is no trusted root certificate in the chain. Authority key identifier of signature certificate matches subject key identifier of root certificate even inside Adobe Reader. If the root certificate and the user certificate are installed in windows key store, the certificate chain is shown.

If we derive the user certificate with openssl instead of Java/bouncycastle and sign a pdf with it, everything looks fine, but the java generated certificate fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Root Certificate is <[Root Cert](http://mknaus.bplaced.net/public.cer)>
PDF signed with openssl generated certificate: <[openssl pdf](http://mknaus.bplaced.net/5a45cb2220ff2adbfb58efb42fc3bbfb.pdf)>

Comment: Please supply the public root certificate and a sample PDF to inspect.

Comment: At first glance your root certificate seems to miss the key usage extension. RFC 3280/5280 states that *Conforming CAs MUST include this extension in certificates that contain public keys that are used to validate digital signatures on other public key certificates.* But you say you also have a user certificate issued by the same root certificate generated with openssl which works. Thus, there seems to be something else to look for. Thus, please also supply a PDF signed with that other user certificate properly verifiable by Adobe Reader. BTW, have you considered embedding the chain in the sig

Comment: I added the key usage extensions without any effect.

Comment: @mkl There has been a bunch of edits to our code. Because of this, I cannot reproduce a properly signed document with an openssl user certificate currently (I keep trying providing it). But this and for other reasons I wonder if Adobe Readers error message is misleading and something else is wrong. 
We have tried with the chain in the sig without effect.

Comment: @mkl Provided pdf signed with openssl generated certificate with new root cert.

Comment: Your new root certificate now has a **keyUsage** entry alright, but its **keyCertSign** bit is not set. *The keyCertSign bit is asserted when the subject public key is used for verifying signatures on public key certificates.* [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt)

Comment: @mkl Created new chain without providing files with keyCertSign bit set. No change in Adobe Readers behaviour.